# SELECT COUNT(*) DISTINCT - Finding the total number of times any groups of duplicates appear in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MS-SQL server 2008 r2 I have a table that I'm trying to count the number of groups of duplicates in:

```
id adId
1  a
2  a
3  b
4  c
5  c
6  c
```

I want to find the total number of records that have duplicates in column adId.  The result I want here is 2 (as a and c have both been duplicated)

These do not work as they count the duplicate rows and not the groups of duplicates

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT adId FROM oc_cal_sc) 
HAVING COUNT(adId) > 1

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (adId)) AS TotalRecords 
FROM oc_cal_sc 
HAVING COUNT(adId) > 1

SELECT SUM(temp_1.adId) as TotalRecords 
FROM 
    (SELECT adId, count(1) AS count_1 
    FROM oc_cal_sc GROUP BY adId HAVING adId >1) 
as temp_1
```

Any ideas on how to go about this as I'm a little out of my depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the records which have duplicates:

```
SELECT adId,COUNT(adId) AS TotalRecords 
FROM oc_cal_sc
GROUP BY adId
HAVING COUNT(adId) > 1
```

With the example you have given, result would be:

```
adId    TotalRecords
a       2
c       3
```

**EDIT:**

For getting the **number of records** which have duplicates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotDuplicates
FROM
(SELECT adId,COUNT(adId) AS TotalRecords 
    FROM oc_cal_sc
    GROUP BY adId
    HAVING COUNT(adId) > 1) T
```

Result would be:

```
TotDuplicates
2
```

Comment: @Dwair - Why was this accepted?  You state that you want an answer of `2`, but this will generate a pair of tuples (`('a', 2)` and `('c', 3)`).  Do you need to update your question?  Or does this answer need to be changed?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: I suppose OP needed to find the records which have duplicates. Anyway, added both cases to my answer. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) TotalRecords
FROM (
  SELECT
    adId,
    COUNT(1)
  FROM oc_cal_sc
  GROUP BY adId
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your query as inner query and get the total count in the outer query:

```
select count(inner_count) AS TotalRecords from (
    select count(adId) AS inner_count
    from oc_cal_sc
    group by adId
    having count(adId) > 1
) x
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfGroups 
FROM (
   SELECT aid FROM oc_cal_sc
   GROUP BY aid
   HAVING COUNT(aid) > 1
) T
```